# "[WinError 5] Access is denied" error when moving a file (Python)

Tags: python

I am learning python and I come across to this exception error when im trying to move a file on a different directory, Apparently I don't have an access to do those things. I have already tried to run my Pycharm IDE as an administrator and it did nothing...

```
import os

src = "C:\\INSTALLER\\sample_text.txt"
dst = "C:\\Users\\mats\\Desktop"

try:
    os.replace(src,dst)
    print("File successfully moved...")
except Exception as x:
    print(x)
    print("\nSomething happened! :(")
```

Comment: Are you able to move the file using Windows Explorer?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.replace): `If dst is a directory, OSError will be raised.`

Comment: It worked, you need to also put a file in a destination like overwriting it. Thank you very much error no more.

Comment: Clarification: You need to put the file that you want to move in the destination also, it should be like this: dst = "C:\\Users\\mats\\Desktop\\sample_text.txt"